# Flask application not working when using thread pool (using UWSGI)

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing, uwsgi

Im implementing multithreaded functionality in Flask using multiprocessing ThreadPools.

My problem is that is does not work. When the threadpool is activated the  application halts.

If I restart the UWSGI server it cannot gracefully kill the threads, so it waits for a few minutes before performing a kill -9:

`worker 1 (pid: 369) is taking too much time to die...NO MERCY !!!`

**Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?**

My code looks like this (simplified a bit):

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

    class BattleController():
        pool = None

        def __init__(self):
            self.pool = ThreadPool(2)

        def do_work(self, info):
            # This function is executed by a background thread.
            print info

        def start_async_work(self, info):
            self.pool.map(self.do_work, [info])
```

My view looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
controller = BattleController()

@app.route('/api/test', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    controller.start_async_work("Some info to process")
    return "everything worked", 200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask is not designed to support what you are trying to do: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/design/#thread-locals

Answer (score 2):

For future readers:
It is not possible to do what I'm trying to do (as Oin pointed out), but I did find an alternative:
[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) looks like a nice [Flask plug-in](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/) that enables background tasks.